# Lifting of Automorphisms to the normalisation

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $X$ be a nodal curve, and let $\phi\in Aut(X)$. Let $\tilde{X}$ its normalisation.

> Is there a condition on $\phi$ to be lift to $\tilde{X}$?
>
> How about involutions?

Thanks

Comment: $\phi$ induces a map $\phi \circ \nu : \widetilde X \to X$, where $\nu:\widetilde X\to X$ is the normalization. By universal property of the normalization of a variety, this map lifts to a map $\widetilde \phi : \widetilde X \to \widetilde X$. Now if you do this construction with $\phi^{-1}$, you find a lift $\widetilde {\phi^{-1}}$ such that $\widetilde \phi \circ \widetilde{\phi^{-1}}$ is the identity map of $\widetilde X$ on a dense open set, thus everywhere. Therefore $\widetilde \phi $ is an automorphism of $\widetilde X$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normalization is a functor. This means that automorphisms, as well as involutions, lift canonically.